# Proof verification: If $f$ is holomorphic in $\{\operatorname{Im} z \ge 0\}$ and bounded then $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $f$ be holomorphic in $\{\operatorname{Im}(z) \ge 0\}$, real on the real axis and bounded. Show that $f$ is constant.

**My attempt:** Extend $f$ to the whole plane by defining $g(z)=f(z)$ if $\operatorname{Im}(z)\ge 0$ anf $g(z)=\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ if $\operatorname{Im}(z)< 0$. Since $f$ is real on the real axis, $g$ is well-defined and continuous. It is easy to check, using Cauchy-Riemann equations, that $g$ is entire. But $f$ is bounded, then so is $g$. Therefore, $g$ and, consequently $f$ is constant.

Is this correct?

Comment: It is correct. But is it really easy to check Cauchy-Riemann equations? Note that you not only need to check the values of the equations, but also show differentiability. I find it painful. I would rather invoke [Schwarz reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle) or check that $g$ is entire using [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem).

Comment: But if f is analytic, then its real and imaginary parts are $C^{\infty}$ right?