# Show that $g$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f$ be holomorphic in $\{\operatorname{Im}(z) \ge 0\}$, real on the real axis and bounded. Show that $f$ is constant

**My attempt** : I found the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3434567/proof-verification-if-f-is-holomorphic-in-operatornameim-z-ge-0-and)

But i don't want to used schwarz reflection principle

**My approach**: Define  a function $g : Imz \ge 0 \to \mathbb{C}$  by $g(z)= f(z) - \overline{f(z)} $ where $\overline{f(z)}$ represent  conjugate  of  $f(z)$

Then $g$ is an analytics  function  and all real number are zeroes of $g$

Now if $g$ were non constant , then the set of zeroes  of are  isolated so zeros  will be countable   but here $g$ has uncountably many zeroes and non isolated.

so we get  a  contradiction

Therefore  $g$ must be constant

this implies $f$ is constant

Hence proved

Is my proof/approached is correct or not ?

Comment: Are you sure that $g$ is analytic? for example, if $f(z)=z$, then $g(z)=z-\bar{z}$, this is not analytic!

Comment: ya  @ JustDroppedin     because    domain is $ imz >0$

Comment: so? $\bar{z}$ is nowhere analytic

Comment: You have to conjugate twice, i.e. arguments AND values

Comment: mmm you are right @JustDroppedIn

Comment: @Salcio u mean $g(z)=f(z)-\overline{f(\overline{z})}?$

Comment: yes, other-wise you would have conjugate in Taylor series expansion of $f(z)$ and "conjugate" is not analytic.By taking two conjugates you "move" conjugates to coefficients which are just numbers, i.e. some constant params.

Comment: mm u r right... i got after reading the solution jose carlos sir @Salcio

Comment: I meant to say that in the lower half space $g(z)=\overline{f(\overline{z})}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is not correct because it assumes that $\overline f$ is an analytic function. In general, it is not. The only analytic functions $f$ with connected domain such that $\overline f$ is also analytic are the constant functions.